How do I properly get Node.JS processes to end programmatically?
I am currently developing an NPM module for use with NX. In this module, I have 2 child processes that I am spawning and no matter what I have done it just won't work unless I am debugging it manually. One of the main reasons this is as concerning to me as it is, is that the NX process won't close until both of the child processes finish. For clarification, both of these processes start a server of some kind for the sake of E2E tests. I am also developing this on a windows machine. So for context, process.platform will always return 'win32'
I am spawning these child processes like so:
function startServer(cwd: string, command: string): () => void {
    const serverProcess = spawn(command, {
        cwd,
        shell: true,
        detached: process.platform !== 'win32',
        stdio: 'inherit'
    });

    return () => {
        if (process.platform === 'win32') {
            // Here I have tried a variety of things
            kill(serverProcess.pid); // using the method provided by the npm module 'tree-kill'
            spawn('taskkill', ['/pid', serverProcess.pid.toString(), '/f', '/t']); // this one works when I am debugging manually
            serverProcess.kill(); // this was the first thing I tried and it just seemed to sit there
            process.kill(serverProcess.pid) // also tried with .kill(-serverProcess.pid)
        } else {
            process.kill(-serverProcess.pid, 'SIGINT');
        }
    }
}

The purpose of returning the function is so that I can do something similar to this:
const killEmulators = startServer('<expected directory>', '<emulator command>');
const killDevServer = startServer('<expected server directory>', '<dev server command>');
const result = runTestsThatNeedTheseServers();
killDevServer();
killEmulators();
return result;

Unfortunately, what I have been seeing happen is the NX process shows as still running in my IDE, and running netstat -ano gives me process ID's that match the PID's of each of the server processes.
Ultimately, my question is what am I doing wrong/how should I be killing these processes?

child_process.spawn needs the detached option set to not wait for children to exit. On Windows there's more caveats, so it'd be good to dig into that.

How about instead of trying to kill the child process, send it a message asking it to terminate. Here is a very rough demo:
// Parent
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const c = spawn('node', ['child.js'], { stdio: [ 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc' ] });

c.once('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Killing child');
    c.send('I am here');
}, 6000);

// Child
var interval;

process.once('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(`child received message: ${msg}`);
    console.log('Exiting child');
    clearInterval(interval);
    process.exit(0);
});

var i = 0;
interval = setInterval(() => console.log(`child iteration ${i++}`), 1000);

Anyway, just a thought.

Unfortunately, since the process i am spawning are spawned via commands similar to npx firebase emulators:start, I don't have the option to set it up like that. However if I did have that option, that would be awesome

Oh I see. Foolishly I made the assumption that they too were node scripts.
